# How to select specific sheets in Excel if i have more than hundred worksheets?

Tags: excel

I have a master excel document with more than 300 worksheets inside. I want to select first 150 worksheets but i don't want to do this one by one yet it will be very time consuming. Is there any easy way for me to select first 150 worksheets?

Thank you,
Senol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a programming question. please refer such questions to "superuser.com".

in any case the answer is click the first, hold the shift key, and click the last.